# Union two Spark dataframe and add new column to identify latest date

Tags: python, pyspark

Say I have two dataframes

First dataframe has values for `value` column (unique for each id)

```
id   date          value  some_other_columns...
1    2020-10-01    'a'    
2    2020-09-30    'b'    
2    2020-10-01    'b'
3    2020-10-01    'c'
```

Second dataframe has null values for `value` column

```
id   date          value  some_other_columns...
1    2020-10-02    NULL
2    2020-10-02    NULL
4    2020-10-02    NULL
5    2020-10-02    NULL
6    2020-10-02    NULL
```

I want to union these two dataframes and create a new column `is_active` to determine the latest date grouped by id (but keep other columns) and assign `value` from second dataframe if `id` exists from first dataframe

```
id   date          value  some_other_columns... is_active
1    2020-10-01    'a'                          0
1    2020-10-02    'a'                          1
2    2020-09-30    'b'                          0
2    2020-10-01    'b'                          0
2    2020-10-02    'b'                          1
3    2020-10-01    'c'                          1
4    2020-10-02    NULL                         1
5    2020-10-02    NULL                         1
6    2020-10-02    NULL                         1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your two dataframes to be `df_1` and `df_2` respectively. In order to assign `values` for `df_2`, from `df_1`, you can do a `left join`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df_1_ = df_1.select("id", "value").withColumnRenamed("id", "id_1")

df_2 = df_2.drop("value").join(df_1_, (df_2.id == df_1_.id_1), "left")\
            .drop("id_1").distinct()

df_2.show()
+---+----------+-----+                                                          
| id|      date|value|
+---+----------+-----+
|  1|2020-10-02|    a|
|  2|2020-10-02|    b|
|  4|2020-10-02| null|
|  5|2020-10-02| null|
|  6|2020-10-02| null|
+---+----------+-----+
```

Now to get the `is_active` column, you can union and then use window functions (`row_number()` or `rank()` depending on your need):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy(desc("date"))

df_1.union(df_2).withColumn("is_active", F.when(row_number().over(w)==1, 1)\
        .otherwise(0)).orderBy("id", "date").show()
+---+----------+-----+---------+                                                
| id|      date|value|is_active|
+---+----------+-----+---------+
|  1|2020-10-01|    a|        0|
|  1|2020-10-02|    a|        1|
|  2|2020-09-30|    b|        0|
|  2|2020-10-01|    b|        0|
|  2|2020-10-02|    b|        1|
|  3|2020-10-01|    c|        1|
|  4|2020-10-02| null|        1|
|  5|2020-10-02| null|        1|
|  6|2020-10-02| null|        1|
+---+----------+-----+---------+
```